# How to add a button control to trigger a power automate flow from Azure work item

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, power-automate, workitem

**Hi, As there's no any direct integration from Azure DevOps to SharePoint, I've created a powerautomate flow to create a link in the work item which directs to a sharepoint folder which is created in the background upon on saving the work item. But the flow is really slow and I would like to add a button to the work item that will trigger the particular flow, so the link will be appear upon on clicking the button. Any ideas on a work around for this?**

I refered this to create the flow

https://danikahil.com/2021/11/requirements-details-including-attachments-azure-devops-integration-with-teams-and-sharepoint.html

Comment: have you tried Sam‘s suggestion to use webhook trigger? Can it make your flow faster? You can also try to use the REST API in the DevOps pipeline to [create a folder in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/805011/creating-folder-in-sharepoint-site-from-postman), and then [update the fields of the work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP). The pipeline can be triggered by the webhook, the trigger event will be work item update.

Comment: Can you guide me with step by step on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, the link won't appear when clicking the button, the flow will still need to run to create the folder and then update the work item.

An avenue to explore, is change your flow to be triggered by an HTTP Request, then look at using Azure DevOps webhooks to call your flow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops

I suspect this may quicker than the On Item Created trigger. And if not, then you can look to add a link to your flow with the same HTTP Request trigger, to your work item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I add a HTTP trigger to the current flow at the begining? In that case should I remove the "When a work item is created" connetor?

Comment: Yes correct, you will also need to get the current work item from the request body.

Comment: When i try to save to generate the URI of HTTP Request I get the error message "
Flow save failed with code 'CannotDisableTriggerConcurrency' and message 'The trigger 'When_a_work_item_is_created' of current version of workflow 'xxxxxxxx' has concurrency runtime configuration specified. Trigger concurrency runtime configuration cannot be removed once specified.'."

Comment: You'll need to create a new flow. I think you should be able to do a `Save As` to make a copy. Then you should be able to remove it (ensure you leave it switched off till after you  remove that trigger).

Comment: Perfect, HTTP trigger has been worked successfully to call to the powerautomate flow from Azure DevOps.